# Why does this Adjacency List Produce Error On Input >= 7914?

Tags: c

#### Problem

The following adjacency matrix works for all numbers from 1 to 7913.

Whenever the user inputs 7914 or greater, it produces the following error:

#### Error

Exception Thrown at 0x009818B9 Access Violation Reading Location 0x00550004

#### Error Location

1. Error located in method `addEdge()`
2. Error located at the code `newNode->next = graph->array[dest].head`

#### Question:

Why does it work for the input 1 to 7913, but throws an access violation at any number greater than or equal to 7914?

Code has been fixed

```
//edit_removed_code
```

Comment: What?  Every line of that code generates an AV?  If not, please tell us which line generated the exception as you stepped through with your debugger.

Comment: I have written a comment of the issue. So, if I write `addEdge(graph, 7914, 8000)` it will produce an exception. This exception points to `newNode->next = graph->array[dest].head` located under method `addEdge`. This code is what generates the exception.

Comment: My apologies - I did not see that, maybe I'm too tired:(

Comment: I retracted ny downvote and closevote.  Note that I made a pointless edit, (added a blank line at the end, no other changes), in order to allow the downvote removal:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int V = 5;
struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V);
```

--> every node `>=5` will cause undefined behavior.

It works for 7913 just by accident which is caused by the implementation of your platform's memory allocation (which might reserve whole PAGE_SIZE aligned areas).

Do not rely on such a behavior and allocate enough memory resp. catch invalid node numbers!

Comment: Also, you should just add code in your functions to validate that `src` and `dest` node numbers are `< V`.